# how to create an array of string or float in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i need some help here, i need to know how to create an array of string retrieved from an array. i'm using powerplot for graph and it only accept float or string array.

i need to create something something like this dynamically.

NSString * sourceData[7] = {@"2", @"1", @"4", @"8", @"14", @"15", @"10"};

Below are my code to find out the numbers in strings.

```
NSInteger drunked = [appDelegate.drinksOnDayArray count];
NSMutableArray * dayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * sdArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//float *sdArray[7];


for (int i=0; i<drunked; i++) {
    DayOfDrinks *drinksOnDay = [appDelegate.drinksOnDayArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString * dayString= [NSDate stringForDisplayFromDateForChart:drinksOnDay.dateConsumed];
    [dayArray addObject:dayString];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dayArray objectAtIndex:i]);

    drinksOnDay.isDetailViewHydrated = NO;
    [drinksOnDay hydrateDetailViewData];

    NSString * sdString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", drinksOnDay.standardDrinks];
    [sdArray addObject:sdString];

    NSString *tempstring;
    NSLog(@"%@",[sdArray objectAtIndex:i]);

}
```

thanks for the help :)

Comment: what is exactly the problem your have with your code?

Comment: i need to dynamically create a list of String or Float like this 
NSString * sourceData[7] = {@"2", @"1", @"4", @"8", @"14", @"15", @"10"};

what i have now is an array with objects inside, i dun know how to add string in a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array's in Objectice-C aren't that hard to work with:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[myArray addObject:@"first string"]; // same with float values
[myArray addObject:@"second string"];
[myArray addObject:@"third string"];
int i;
int count;
for (i = 0, count = [myArray count]; i < count; i = i + 1)
{
   NSString *element = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
   NSLog(@"The element at index %d in the array is: %@", i, element); // just replace the %@ by %d
}
```

You can either use `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` - depending on your needs, they offer different functionality.

Following tutorial covers exactly what you are looking after:

http://www.cocoalab.com/?q=node/19

Comment: hi shaharyar,
thanks for the reply, however this is not what i want. i know how an array works, but i need to know how to dynamically create a list of string like this 

NSString * sourceData[7] = {@"2", @"1", @"4", @"8", @"14", @"15", @"10"};

what i have now is an array with objects inside, i dun know how to add string in a string.

Comment: how to add string in a string? your question isn't very clear there. please clarify. your question says : `how to create an array of string or float in Objective-C` | that's what I answered.

Comment: @Shaharyar The float array isn't working for me! when I addObject it says sending 'float' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the elements to the array when you init (and optionally add them later only if you are using the `Mutable` version of a collection class:

```objective-c
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2", @"1", @"4", @"8", @"14", @"15", @"10", nil];
[myArray addObject:@"22"];
[myArray addObject:@"50"];

//do something

[myArray release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use malloc to create a C-style array. something like this should work:

```
NSString **array = malloc(numElements * sizeof(NSString *))
some code here
free(array)
```

Be aware that unlike NSMutable array, c arrays won't do a retain, so you have to manage it if needed. And don't forget the free

Comment: Hi Luis,

Could you give me more info on how to run the loop ?

Comment: You just have a C array, a standar for loop should work. For instance, for (int i =0; i<numElements; i++) {
  NSString *elem = array[i];
}